# Selecting matching photos from file server and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I made a program where a photo and photo name is stored in a file server and the name, id, and other info a `MYSQL` Database.

If I have `user "1"` and they have a photo named `"cat.jpg"` which the name is stored in the file server and the database, how can I differ that photo between `user 2's` `"cat.jpg"`?

CONTENT OF /userphotos

```
cat.jpg  //uploaded by user 1

dog.jpg //uploaded by user 1

cat.jpg  //uploaded by user 2
```

**MYSQL:**

```
USERID = "1" PHOTOID ="1" PHOTONAME = "cat.jpg" 

USERID = "2" PHOTOID ="2" PHOTONAME = "cat.jpg"
```

How can I get the right cat.jpg according to the user? Do I have to have the photos in /userphotos named by the PHOTOID instead?

Comment: How do you have two files of the same name in the same folder? Are you certain one wasn't overwritten?

Comment: @Cfreak Oh yes your right but I guess my question is how can I make this work? It would work if I had the photoid as the photoname wouldn't it? What is the "common practice"? How could I have unique names?

Comment: @greg's answer is a very good solution. You still see the name of the image and it's uniquely identified by the user.

Comment: @Cfreak What if the same user adds a different photo named the same?

Comment: The easiest thing in that case is to give the file a generated name. Using `md5` on the file contents is a good solution for this because then you could save space by combining user's files that are the same file.  You then need to store the filename in the database. Since the user has more than one file you probably want to create a separate table for it.

Comment: @Cfreak Can you give me an example? What am I hashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it with the name of the image + the username Ex: user1_cat.jpg and user2_cat.jpg

Comment: What if the same user adds a different photo named the same?

Comment: So an other alternative is to create a file that is named by the date using the php date() function.

Comment: and if they upload at the same time?

Comment: Include the milliseconds in the date and time... There are very, very, very little chances they submit at the same millisecond :-)